Spacing around & and &= in align and similar environments
I am using the amsmath package but I am not sure about the correct way to type some things (I could not find any information about this in the amsmath user's guide, but maybe I did not see it, so if it is there I would be glad to know it):

In a split environment, should I leave a space between the &'s or not? I mean, should I write a & =b+c, a&=b+c or something else? I have the same question when using align.
In a gather environment, is there a difference between a = b and a=b?


There is not difference, it may only help you to better see equation structure already in editor :-)

spaces never make a difference in math

Thanks for the quick answers to both of you. I did know about the behaviour of white spaces in math mode, but I was not sure with these commands. So, just to confirm, the behave in matrix environments is the same, it is not?

you don't need to know of any special space behaviour of & the cells of align and gather are math mode so my first comment would apply. matrix and array environments actually share code with tabular and so explicitly ignore the spaces, but even if they did not, the spaces would not affect the output.
